# How to run a wordpress cron job using a schedule hook?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to run a custom cron job using a wp function. I tried to follow [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216121/26593) but the piece below is not running.

I need t run `wp_remote_get` every 5 minutes.

In function.php I do:

```
$args = array(false);
function schedule_my_cron(){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '5min', 'my_schedule_hook', $args);
}
if(!wp_next_scheduled('my_schedule_hook',$args)){
    add_action('init', 'schedule_my_cron');
}

function my_schedule_hook() {
  wp_remote_get('https://example.com/wp-content/themes/JikuHealth/scripts/covid-19_global_data.php');
}
```

[wp docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) but I still don't understand how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_schedules/) supported recurrences are ‘hourly’, ‘twicedaily’, ‘daily’, and ‘weekly’. You are using '5min' but have you created it yet? This is an example:

```
function custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['5min'] = array('interval' => 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS, 'display' => 'Every 5 minutes');
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_schedule' );
```

EDIT

Full code for your example

```
// Your custom recurrences: '5min' , '20min'
    function custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
       if(!isset($schedules['5min'])){
         $schedules['5min'] = array(
           'interval' => 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS,
           'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
       }
       if(!isset($schedules['20min'])){
         $schedules['20min'] = array(
           'interval' => 20 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS,
           'display' => __('Once every 20 minutes'));
       }
       return $schedules;
    }
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_schedule' );

// Your function
  function my_schedule_hook() {
    //do your stuff
    wp_remote_get('https://example.com/wp-content/themes/JikuHealth/scripts/covid-19_global_data.php');
  }

// Schedule Cron Job Event
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('name_your_cron')) {
      //You can now use '5min', '20min' or any of the default here
      wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'name_your_cron' );
  }
  add_action( 'name_your_cron', 'my_schedule_hook' );
```

Comment: oh right! thanks! Just to confirm `cron_schedules` should be function `my_schedule_hook() {` right? just for future users

Comment: I mean can you please post a complete answer to run that cron as per the question? I have been hours trying to understand how to and this could help future users. Thanks

Comment: Just to know, what to do if we would like to change the time? Should we do `20 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS`  and set it as `20min` and so on right?

Comment: last question, is it valid to run two or more `wp_remote_get` within my_schedule_hook()?

Comment: Updated. Your my_schedule_hook() is a php function, you can do whatever you want there, whatever would have been valid if you called the function manually.