# If the product does not have the "_price" meta key, remove the product

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created code as below and the focus part is `PM.meta_key !='_price'` and I don't know how true it is, it didn't work but it's also possible to remove all products otherwise, I need a correct way.

Also here is a picture, some products don't have the "_price" key and this way the product looks very bad, the strange thing is that they are still in stock.

Here is an example photo.

[image: Example, this product does not have the "_price" key]

```
add_action( 'init', 'automatically_trash_instock_empty_price' );
  function automatically_trash_instock_empty_price() {
              
    // Get any existing copy of our transient data
    if ( false === ( $automatically_trash_instock_empty_price = get_transient( 'automatically_trash_instock_empty_price' ) ) ) {
        
        // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query( "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} P JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} PM ON P.ID = PM.post_id SET P.post_status='trash' WHERE P.post_type='product' and PM.meta_key != '_price'" );

        set_transient( 'automatically_trash_instock_empty_price', true, 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked for MySQL query but why not use native functions for this? You can query all your products and `foreach` create a product object using the following function:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
```

And after that you will be able to access all product's data. All available methods can [be found here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html), but the ones you probably need are:

```
$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```

Then check if `$product->get_price();` is null, empty and/or zero and just:

```
wp_trash_post($product->get_id());
```

[Trash post doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trash_post/)

Finally, you could also set this up [as a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536069/5397117) to run daily/weekly and clean up your products regularly.

EDIT

As per your comments here is a full working example of a scheduled function via wp-cron to do what you asked regularly:

```
 // Your scheduled function
function trash_products_without_price_stock() {
    $get_all = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        )
    );
    if ( $get_all->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $get_all->have_posts() ) :
            $get_all->the_post();
            // Start : Your conditionals here
            if ( ! get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock', true ) ) {
                wp_trash_post( get_the_ID() );
            }
            // End
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
 
// Schedule Cron Job Event
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'clean_my_products' ) ) {
    // here you can use 'hourly', 'twicedaily', 'daily', and 'weekly'
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'clean_my_products' );
}
add_action( 'clean_my_products', 'trash_products_without_price_stock' );
```

Put the above in `functions.php`

Comment: `wp_trash_post()` I hadn't thought of that, I think a condition like `if ( ! get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ) )` would work. 
Am I correct to use something like `wp_trash_post( $product )` to target products after conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can use a post/product ID with `wp_trash_post()` to send it to Trash after meeting your conditions. You can also get it with `$product->get_id()` but it is possible that you already know the ID, if you are looping through an array of product IDs or you are in the Loop (`get_the_ID()`).

Comment: `if ( ! get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock', true ) ) {   wp_trash_post();  }` Is it true that `wp_tras-post()` will target all posts when there is no ID? So how can I run it, with cron?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a full working example as per your comment above.

Comment: This code looks very good and I added it to run it and I learned a few things about cron, thanks for your help!